# Multiple image in OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers-2, layers, image

I'm trying to add multiple images to OpenLayers. I have the following (some code is excluded):

```
var images = [image1,image2,image3] // these are url images on my server    
var image = new OpenLayers.Map($('#image'),
               {
                   units: 'pixels'
               });
// add a bunch of controls including layer switcher.
var vectorLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Vector Layer");

for(var i =0; i < images.length; I++)
{
  var info = getInfo(images[i]);
  var viewPort = image.getViewport();
  var viewHeight = jQuery(viewPort).height();
  var viewWidth = jQuery(viewPort).width();
  var graphic = new OpenLayers.Layer.Image(
                        info.name,
                        images[i],
                        new OpenLayers.Bounds(0, 0, info.width, info.height),
                        new OpenLayers.Size(vw * 0.9, vh * 0.9)
                    );
  image.addLayers([graphic,vectorLayer]);
  image.zoomToMaxExtent();
}
```

This is a fairly simple example of what I am doing and I can see the images are getting loaded. All three images are different sizes (small, medium, large).

Once everything is loaded and I can see the last image loaded perfectly:

1. I switch to the middle image the scale and positioning are all wrong.
2. I switch back to the last image and the scale is right.
3. I zoom into the image (last one)
4. I switch back to the middle image and I can't see anything any more.

I'm not too sure if what I want to do is even possible, but here goes. I want to load all images but have them all independent. So when I zoom into one image the state isn't the same on another.

Please can someone offer advice?